# R markdown: Why Rmarkdown displays no references?

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

I am trying to use reference in the R Markdown. When I try to export the markdown to pdf or anything, I receive no error!

But the references do not appear:

I have it as this in the beginning:

```
---
title: "Gap"
author: "xyz"
date: "19/09/2018"
bibliography: ref.bib
output: pdf_document
---
```

I changed the name to ref2.bib (only in the R file) and in that case I do get an error saying it does not find a file... So based on that I do know it is finding the file but it is not displaying the references... (I have also tried using different references). What could I be doing wrong?

If there would be an error it would be easier to reproduce, but I see nothing that's the issue:
It's a pretty dumb example
[image]
And the bib file is in the same folder
[image]

And I don't see the bib.ref

Comment: Please make this question *reproducible*. This includes a small representative markdown document in addition to the yaml header you've provided.

Comment: In latex I believe one has to compile a document twice to get the bibliography to show up.  I don't know why, but that is always my experience.  Perhaps your problem is a variant on that issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You need to reference your bibliography file in your .Rmd file.**

So in your example would have to add:

```
[@valiant1990bridging]
```

*The below thread has quite a useful example:*

[Including Bibliography in RMarkdown document with use of the knitcitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32946203/including-bibliography-in-rmarkdown-document-with-use-of-the-knitcitations)

Answer (score 1):

I was not citing it. It is my first time using this, I wanted to do a quick example, but apparently if you do not cite it with the @ symbol, there reference will not appear; and it makes sense you don't want to reference stuff you don't cite at all.

Comment: Basically was typing that up in a formal answer...