# How to indent a numbered list of references in R markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, bibliography

I have been trying to indent a numbered list of references in r markdown, but I have not been successful till now.

This is what I want:

```
 [1]  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
      aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

 [2]  bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
      bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
 ...

 [9]  ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
      ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc

[10]  ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
      ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
```

And I get it (numbers right-aligned and text indented) in texstudio by using:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{[#1] \hspace{0.2cm}}
\makeatother
```

But this is what I get in R markdown pdf output:

```
[1] aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
   aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

[2] bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
   bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
...

[9] ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
   cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc

[10] dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
   dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
```

when using:

```
\setlength{\parindent}{-0.5cm}
\setlength{\leftskip}{0.5cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{8pt}
\noindent
```

My YAML Header:

```
documentclass: book
fontsize: 11pt
classoption: twoside
geometry: margin=2.5cm
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    toc: no
    fig_caption: yes
    keep_tex: yes
    latex_engine: xelatex
    number_sections: yes
    includes: 
      before_body: titlepage.tex
      in_header: preamble.tex
dev: cairo_pdf
always_allow_html: yes
tables: true
bibliography: library.bib
csl: elsevier-vancouver.csl 
urlcolor: black
linkcolor: black
link-citations: yes
```

Comment: Not sure if this is about R markdown. Maybe this can be answered here [https://tex.stackexchange.com/](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: In latex I have no problem doing what I want, so I guess the issue regards R markdown. Besides, similar questions (e.g., [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52906477/manually-indent-references-in-an-r-markdown-document?rq=1)) have been asked and answered here ;)